# Missing Intellisense in visual studio 2012

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2012, resharper, intellisense

I was sitting and coding some razor stuff in a `.cshtml` file, and must have pressed something accidentally, cause suddenly my intellisense didn't popup automatically, i have to press `Ctrl+space`, but the intellisense in normal c# files like `.cs` works perfectly?

BTW. i have ReSharper installed (if i might affect the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by reinstalling ReSharper, removing ReSharper temp files, and disabling, then re-enable IntelliSense manually in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages + C#.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has released an update for Visual Studio 2012 to fix this issue.

[Announcing release of ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Comment: Hooray!   Finally a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio

1. Tools
2. Import and Export Settings
3. Select Reset all settings.**Notice that this will reset all your settings.**
4. Now select Visual C#(or which language your prefer) Development settings
5. Hit Finish

If that doesn't work, try going to:
\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11\Common7\IDE
 and execute devenv /setup from the command line and try again.

Comment: After the reset i cant even use ctrl+space :S

Comment: Try to boot your computer after reset

Comment: Ah intellisense wont work after reset because it for some reason suddenly cant find RazorRocks method in all my umbraco templates...
Not sure why the reset of settings affects that ?

Comment: Maybe it had more to do with restarting visual studio then resetting the settings.

Comment: No cause if i revert back to before i reset, it find RazorRocks fine...

So im still kinda stranded...

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact problem.  (Note I am in a VB environment)

I went into Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->Basic
I saw that under the "Statement Complete" header the following were NOT checked:
[] Auto list member 
[] Parameter information

I went ahead and CHECKED these options and auto complete in Razor views was restored.